# Default SSH/Telnet Terminal Size

Tags: blackberry, ssh, terminal, telnet

I'm writing an SSH/Telnet client for the Blackberry (and for other hand-held devices).

My question is more related to usability.  Due to the screen size limitations for certain devices, and resolutions, how should I set the default rows/columns for the screen?

Currently I am setting it to 80 columns.  The number of rows is dependent on the size of the font to prevent scrolling.

I have heard that 80x24 is the defacto default for most terminal types.  Is this true?

For those SSH/Telnet users out there, how would you like your rows/columns set by default for a terminal client on a handheld device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[80×25](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/80x25) is actually more typical.

BTW. Don't know about BlackBerry, but for other smartphones and handhelds, there are [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) ports.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer apps that detect the terminal size (with `stty -a` or the moral equivalent) and most apps do this.  So I think the more important question would be, does your client properly report the size to the remote applications, so they can size themselves accordingly?

P.S. I'd be personally interested in such an app--the existing Blackberry ssh clients aren't great.  If you want to follow up, my user name followed by my domain name ("reality") followed by the tld (com) may be used for sending electronic correspondence.  (Screen scrape that, spambots!)

Answer (score 1):

Most Telnet emulators uses 24x80 mode, which is used for VT100 type terminals.

Some users prefer a XTERM type emulator, which does not have a fixed width/height.

You can see my Telnet - ssh-2 version for blackberry at http://mochasoft.dk/telnetbb.htm